# Memory Mapped Stream - Wait for data to arrive

Tags: c#, callback, stream, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to make application A write an byte array into a Memory Mapped Stream, application B then reads this piece of memory. I've got to the point where they can read and write but the problem is I can't get application B to wait for new data to arrive, right now it just reads as fast as possible.

After searching around for a bit I found out that you could assign a callback to `MemoryMappedStream.BeginRead` but i'm unsure how to use this callback to wait for new data from the stream. How would one make a callback for this kind of situation? Or am I looking into the wrong direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251443/how-to-read-and-write-a-file-using-memory-mapped-file-c  might help you.

Comment: You could use a named [`EventWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) as a signal to the consuming thread to tell it when the data has been completely written. (You might also want another `EventWaitHandle` for the consuming thread to indicate to the producing thread that it has consumed the data)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Definitely looks like a interesting possibility, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MatthewWatson I looked into EvenWaitHandles and managed to make the processen wait upon each other's signal with the use of two `AutoResetEvents`. One of them is used to set `MemoryReadEventWaitHandle` when the reading is performed and the other sets `MemoryWrittenEventWaitHandle` when the writing is done. This way they will not interfere with one another and perform the tasks in correct order.